# How to launch a Python file on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7

this is the first time I have used Python.
I downloaded the file ActivePython-2.7.1.4-win32-x86
and installed it on my computer; I'm using Win7.

So when I tried to run a python program, it appears and disappears very quickly. I don't have enough time to see anything on the screen. I just downloaded the file and double-cliked on it.

How do I launch this file? I know that it is a long file for a first Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or run it from a batch file:

```
myprog.py
pause
```

Has the advantage that you can specify a different version of Python too.

Answer (score 4):

Add the line

```
input()
```

to the end of the program, with the correct indentation. The issue is that after the data is printed to the console the program finishes, so the console goes away. `input` tells the program to wait for input, so the console won't be closed when it finishes printing.

I hope you're not using that program to learn Python; it's pretty complicated!

Answer (score 3):

go to `Start > All programs > Accessories`  and click on `Command Prompt`. then drag the python file from the explorer view into this command line and press `Enter`...

now you can watch the output of the script execution !

Answer (score 2):

run it from a command prompt:

```
> python myscript.py
```

You can also start only the python interpreter from the command prompt (or by running python.exe) and then try some commands:

```
> python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 7
>>> print a+b
9
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit more on this.

You have a script `myscript.py` in a folder `C:\myscripts`. This is how to set up Windows 7 so that you can type `> myscript`  into a CMD window and the script will run.

1) Set your `PATH` variable to include the Python Interpreter.

Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced Settings > Environment Variables. You can set either the System Variables or the User Variables. Scroll down till you find `PATH`, select it, click `Edit`.The Path appears selected in a new dialog. I always copy it into Notepad to edit it though all you need do is add `;C:\Python27` to the end of the list. Save this.

2) Set your `PATH` variable to include `C:\myscripts`

3) Set your `PATHEXT` variable to include `;.PY`.  (This is the bit that saves you from typing `myscript.py`)

This may now just work. Try opening a command window and typing `myscript`

But it may not. Windows can still mess you about. I had installed and then uninstalled a Python package and when I typed `myscript` Windows opened a box asking me which program to use. I browsed for `C:\python27\python.exe` and clicked that. Windows opened another command window ran the script and closed it before I could see what my script had done! To fix this when Windows opens its dialog select your Python and *click the "Always do this" checkbox at the bottom.* Then it doesn't open and close another window and things work as they should. Or they did for me.

Added: Above does not say how to pass arguments to your script. For this see answer [Windows fails to pass arguments to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109582/windows-fails-to-pass-the-args-to-a-python-script)