# Windows fails to pass the args to a python script

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, command-line

in py_script.py:

```
import os
import sys

l = len(sys.argv) 
if  l == 1:
    print 'no args'
else:
    if l > 1: 
        print 'first arg is %s'%sys.argv[1]
    if l > 2:
        print 'second arg is %s'%sys.argv[2]
```

now going command-line, on my winXP platform:

```
d:\path\py_script.py 1 2
```

yields

```
first arg is 1
second arg is 2
```

yet on my Win7 platform I get

```
no args
```

If I do

```
d:\path\python py_script.py 1 2
```

I get

```
first arg is 1
second arg is 2
```

How can I make my Win7 environment act as expected  ?

some details:
win7 is 64bit.
py2.6.6 on win7, py 2.6.4 on winXP.

Comment: Works for me on Win 7 with 2.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on jtp's answer.
Well I messed up with the registry a bit.

This was what I think are the steps:

1. doing

   assoc .py=Python.File
2. through win explorer pick a .py file, right click -> x64 -> open with > browse to c:\Python26\python.exe choose the 'always open with this..' box.
   this in effect changes immediately the reg value

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.py\UserChoice 
   to
    Python.File
3. set HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Open\Command to
   "C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

note: from previous experience i'm sure things are expected to mess up with mixed versions.
uninstalling/re-installing shall be the way to go. BTW, I didn't want to go through that becuase with all the packages including ones I built from source it would be a mess.

Comment: Congratulations on solving the issue.

Comment: Recently had this again with a Win7 32-bit machine. Solution was the same, this time in HKCU\Software\Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command .. got to it by searching the registry for c:\python26\python.exe entries.

Comment: Me also. I changed HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command adding %* thus: "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

Answer (score 5):

I'm using 2.7.1 on Win 7.

If you want to invoke Python programs by file extension alone, you should check the file type associations and command line parameters. I have experienced issues when installing/reinstalling multiple versions of Python on Windows.

```
C:\dv>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\dv>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

This TechNet page can provide some more detailed background.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but `python py_script.py` is the standard way to execute Python scripts.